# How secure is cURL in web2web communications?

Tags: php, curl

I am interested in launching a new website. Let's name it MYWEBSITE. It will have SSL and the server will have DDOS protection.

I want to implement a simple service for a niche, where some mathematical operations take place on the server and are returned to the requesting server/website as hashed (this information should be enough). The information will be fragile!

It will work like this: when a website sends data to my server, the server will return a hashed string, using SHA256. Each website will have his account on MYWEBSITE where he can set the hash key so he can use it to decrypt the data send by MYWEBSITE.

I would like to know which method of sending data between two websites is the most secure. I am thinking about cURL.

I am also thinking to allow users to set a communication hash key in their accounts on MYWEBSITE. This way each website will send the cURL data hashed and his userid unhashed, for network security measures. I would retrieve his userid from the database, get his hashed key and unhash the string.

This way the data traveled safely via cURL. After that, I know the data sent by the website. This data will contain the website secret key, required for authentication. After that MYWEBSITE can return the hashed string for the website.

Each website would send all this data when an user clicks buttonX on websiteB.

Can this method be intercepted by users or anybody else by using network hacks?

Comment: Incidentally, I've removed the unrelated question on website optimisation (it is still visible in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19962553/revisions)) as this makes the question more likely to close. How to optimise a web application is a very broad topic, and probably needs to be asked in a more specific way. I'd advise also that you need to be sure that there is demand for your site first, before you look at optimising. For more on this line of thinking, do a web search for "premature optimisation".

Comment: If the website returns a SHA256 hash, then it cannot be decrypted. Hashing is a one-way function. I think you're going to have to spell out exactly what you want to achieve - you've given a solution but the problem is still unclear.

Comment: Thank you for the accept. My final thought is that your user profiles might contain one half of a public-private key (or contain both halves but require a symmetric password to decrypt the private key). As I say though, making suggestions is harder unless the full detail of the problem is known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If websiteB connects to MYWEBSITE via cURL, then make sure the connection is encrypted.

You can do this with a valid SSL certificate in MYWEBSITE, but make sure you check the validity of that certification in your cURL call. The degree to which this is secure depends on whether you and your cert provider have kept the private key secret; it has been alleged in the news that certain governments have effectively rendered SSL redundant by forcing certificate providers to divulge keys secretly. Nevertheless, for most purposes this approach could still be argued as being "secure enough".

The other approach is for you to do your own public-key encryption, using a well-tested library. This has the advantage that less people have access to the private key - only you, your business staff and your hosting provider can take a copy.

Note that security is not an "on or off" thing - you should decide what threats you are trying to protect against, and what efforts are reasonable to mitigate them. Thus, the security you need for a free online game is likely to be much less than that of an online bank. I recommend reading [Bruce Schneier](https://www.schneier.com/book-beyondfear.html) for some of the theory on this topic.

Comment: My question is: Is the cURL data sent through user to MYWEBSITE? Isn't cURL data sent from websiteB to MYWEBSITE directly, without the intervention of a website visitor? If so, how can it be intercepted? I guess it can be intercepted by someone that listens the network communication line of MYWEBSITE or websiteB, which comes to my next question ... shouldn't that be secured by the datacenter and hosting provider?

Comment: That's a very complex topic. In general, two servers that communicate with each other over the public internet are susceptible to having their traffic intercepted. An adversary would have to be powerful in order to do this, but certainly governments of most first world countries do this quite routinely. Data centers can check their physical security and vet their staff, but those checks are not 100% foolproof. Hence the need for encryption, which I discussed in my contribution above. Bear in mind though that in 99% of cases, server owners do not need to worry about security to this level.

Comment: Whilst the above is good to know, perhaps you would explain what your site does, and then that would give readers an idea of what sort of security you _should_be thinking about. If the website is to publish your favourite recipes, you should scale down your security requirements `:)`.

Comment: I added more details and changed the description of my implementation based on your feedback. Please check and thanks for the help!